# ListView onClick nothing show adapter to CardView detail

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, kotlin, cardview

[image]I have ListView, but when ListView clicked, i want display detail ListView.
But currenly, when i clicked every item in ListView, he always display that item is all.

```
private fun showRecyclerList() {
    lsMenu.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    val listAdapter = ListAdapter(list)
        lsMenu.adapter = listAdapter
            listAdapter.setOnItemClickCallback(object : ListAdapter.OnItemClickCallback {
                override fun onItemClicked(data: Menu) {
                    showRecyclerCard()
                    showSelected(data)

                }
            })
}
```

and this is my cardView

```
private fun showRecyclerCard(){
    lsMenu.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    val cardViewMenuAdapter = CardViewMenu(list)
    lsMenu.adapter = cardViewMenuAdapter
```

Comment: The question is not properly understood, please edit it.

Comment: thankyou! i've been edit it...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: thankyou, i've been edit it....